# Can VS2010 help me find memory leaks?

Tags: silverlight, debugging, visual-studio-2010, memory-leaks

I'm going through the pain right now of finding memory leaks in my application using WinDbg. Luckily, I've found a few good articles that give a very good step-by-step process of how to do it. Still, it is a fairly painful process. Does VS2010 have any built in features that can ease the burden of finding a memory leak in a Silverlight application? Of course, a memory leak in .NET sounds a bit like a misnomer, but what I intend to do is to find all objects that are still referencing an object that I believe should be garbage collected.

For those that may be interested, here are some good articles on how to get started using WinDbg to find memory leaks in Silverlight:

- [Finding Memory Leaks In Silverlight With WinDbg](https://web.archive.org/web/20120519030555/http://davybrion.com/blog/2009/08/finding-memory-leaks-in-silverlight-with-windbg/)
- [Hunting down memory leaks in Silverlight](https://viswaug.wordpress.com/2009/07/13/hunting-down-memory-leaks-in-silverlight/)
- [Where's your leak at? (Using WinDbg, SOS, and GCRoot to diagnose a .NET memory leak)](https://web.archive.org/web/20150629123240/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/delay/archive/2009/03/11/where-s-your-leak-at-using-windbg-sos-and-gcroot-to-diagnose-a-net-memory-leak.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Memory leak in .NET applications [isn't a misnomer at all](http://blog.yapb.net/post/2010/04/08/The-Paradox-of-Safety.aspx). I've had this problem [in applications I've worked on](http://blog.yapb.net/post/2010/03/25/The-Perils-of-Football-Pads.aspx), both Winforms and Webforms.

WinDbg + SOS.dll is painful compared to the [ANTS Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/index.htm). Normally I wouldn't tout a product, but if you're working for a company, they will save a lot of money by buying that product.  It'll save you time having to look for memory leaks, and developer time is almost always more expensive than purchasing an application.

Comment: some other people here at my company have used the ANTS profiler and think highly of it as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't thing VS 2010 has this; I remember Microsoft did have http://memprofiler.com/ as a memory profiler for finding leaks, and there are other third party tools.

HTH.

Comment: .NET Memory Profiler appears to be third-party, not a Microsoft product.  SciTech Software (http://www.scitech.se/) looks like an entirely different Swedish company.